# RegEx Test pattern for LxWxH

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex

I am looking for a regex test pattern that can validate a string describing an item's dimensions.  The string would be formatted LxWxH (e.g. 20x40x10).  It should be able to accept either x or X as a separator.

Right now I have:
`/.*?([0-9](?:\s+x\s+[0-9]+[HWD])*)\s*\-?;/`

Comment: are you talking about php or js now?

Comment: I'm using this example in Javascript but the test pattern would be applicable to php also, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

If I well understood:

```
var size = "20x50x68";

/^\d+x\d+x\d+$/i.test(size);
```

If measure can have optionally decimal parts (e.g. `23.4x59x80.2633333`) the regexp needs to be

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?x\d+(\.\d+)?x\d+(\.\d+)?$/i.test(size);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I'm new to Regex so if you have a second to confirm my suspicions, I'd appreciate it
^ - beginning of string  
\d - any number of repeating digits  
+x - x or X  
$ - end of string?

Comment: @user1026361 : `\d` matches a *single* digit, `[0-9]`. `\d+` matches *one or more* digits. The `+` is known as a *quantifier* : other quantifiers include `*` (zero or more), `?` (zero or one), and `{m,n}` (match between `m` and `n` times.) Have you tried reading the [regular expression flavours reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)?